# Is there a standard way to see if the solution set to a systems of linear equations crosses a given region?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

I'm interested in the following question:

> Determine if there exists a solution to linear system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ that lies in region $R$.

Is there a general procedure for doing so? Currently, I am restricting $R$ to be simple (e.g. the unit hypercube). In the case where $R$ is the unit hypercube, one could interpret this as wanting to find a solution that is a valid probability vector (if one of the equations was $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{1} = 1$, where $\vec{1}$ is the vector of ones).

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the region $R$ is given. If it is a convex polytope this is a special case of the [linear programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) (which generally also has an objective function). Standard software has commands for that, see solving linear system with constraints in [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109146) and [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html).